# Apache as 'user' - security risk?

Tags: php, apache, chmod

I've created a file 'test.txt' and placed it in 'public_html/test_subfolder' on shared hosting server.

Then in TotalCmd I changed the file's chmode to 400 (read for the user, no rights for the group and the outside world).

However, when I request the file via website's URL it opens with no objections. 
I chmoded the 'test_subfolder' to 700 (again read/traverse **only** for the user) **but again** the file can be reached and opened by **any** visitor coming to my website.

Are the following conclusions correct then?

1. Apache service must be configured as 'user'?
2. The above situation is equal to having 777/666 for 'test.txt' and 777 for 'test_subfolder'?
3. It poses serious threat and I should demand my hosting company to reconfigure the server?

Comment: workaround of what you want is use .htaccess to deny direct access and php to access the file with account/permission.

Comment: Thanks Craftein, you mean disable listing the dir's contents via 'Options -Indexes'? Sorry if my qs is trivial; Actually I've hardly payed attention to chmod and always relied on default settings (755, 644 for folders and files respectively). I'm learning;)

Comment: listing of dir's? so i'm guessing you don't have an index.php or html on the dir? because, if you have, your apache will load that file instead of showing you the list of other files in that dir. - in short , you can have an empty index (html/php)... alternatively, you can do what you've said.

Comment: No no. I do have an index.php file, I just understood 'deny access' you mentioned as referring to dir listing; I assume htaccess can also manage access rights to single files?

Comment: yes you can. for individual file or filetype or put password on a directory with htpassword.